# Inserting jQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I'm trying to do a scroll to the top animation with my blog, http://goneintranslation.blogspot.ca with the home link and at the bottom. I think I have the proper coding here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up88cq6n/)

I've read online you but the jQuery code before the < /head> tag in your HTML code

so this is what I did, I inserted the jQuery code within script tags and pasted this code before the < /head> tag in my HTML. After saving my code, the scroll to the top animation does not work. What am I doing wrong? I've read online you have to reference your script tags or something? If that's my mistake how do I reference my script tags or what is the reference to my script tags?

Many Thanks

```js
<script>
  
  $('.home-link').on('click', function(){
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping it in the ready function and make sure jquery is included,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.home-link').on('click', function(){
        $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me!! I'd give you my arm if you need it :')

Comment: Glad to hear it! Actually an accept on the answer would be brilliant :D

Answer (score 1):

I saw your html code in jsfiddle:

> ```
>   <div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-home-link'> <div class="test">
> TOP
>   </div>
>
>   <a class='home-link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' value="go to top">Go to top</a>
> </div>
> ```

Please change the link to:

> `<a class='home-link' href='#'>Go to top</a>`

Comment: Does this make a difference?

Comment: Please check with your jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the code above in the `<head></head>` you can add it at the bottom of the page before the `</body>` tag, what you read about adding jquery to the head was about the link to the jquery library your going to use.

see below for a basic page setup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
        <!-- and the rest of your resource links -->
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <!-- your header html in here -->
        </header>

        <content>

            <!-- 
                where all your main content is 
                with the images and text that is 
                displayed on your page
            -->

            <!-- under all your main content at the bottom add your button/link to scroll back to the top -->
            <a href="#" class="home-link">Scroll To Top</a>

        </content>

        <footer>
            <!-- your footer html in here -->
        </footer>

        <!-- now add your javascript/jquery functions -->
        <script>
        $('.home-link').on('click', function(){
            $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
        }); 
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

There are lots of resources around to read up on and learn all this such as [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) as well asand free online sites to learn code like [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/)

hope this helps.